# How to pass multiple arguments to a python program via windows right-click context menu

Tags: python, windows, arguments, contextmenu

I have a python program which is converted to a windows exe using py2exe. I have also added it to the windows context menu. Basically when one right-clicks on any file another option appears with a link to my exe.

The problem is, when I select multiple files, multiple instances of my program starts up.

Is there any way to pass multiple arguments to the exe?

Thanks,
Sreedhar.

Answer (score 1):

If you add that that exe to windows context menu manually, then you did the hard step manually. What are you looking for is ability for py2exe to handle the [Windows Shell Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703856/open-program-once-with-multiple-files-as-arguments-from-explorer/2704672#2704672), that is not a trivial step and I doubt if it is possible using py2exe itself as I could find no references to in the docs or in the internet.

Comment: Hi,I have used winreg module in python to add the program to the windows context menu. What I need to know is the way to send multiple arguments to the python program via context menu.